# Connecting Entity Framework Docker app to PostgreSQL: 'schema not found' error

Tags: postgresql, docker, entity-framework, microservices

I'm developing a Entity framework app with postgres and net core's docker images. Nevertheless, when Net core app tried to connect postgres database using Npgsql package return me the following message:  `fail: Program[0] : An error occurred creating the DB. Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 3F000: schema "account" does not exist`.

I settle up a docker-compose.yml file like this:

```
`version: '3.7'
services:
  
  web:
    container_name: 'aspnetcoreapp'
    image: netcoreapi:latest
    depends_on:
      - "postgres"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
        - aspnetcoreapp-network
    volumes:
        - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  postgres:
    container_name: 'postgres'
    image: postgres
    environment:
      # change this for a "real" app!
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: db

    networks:
      - aspnetcoreapp-network

networks:
  aspnetcoreapp-network:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  postgres-data:`
```

Later, I settle up the database's connection in `appsettings.json`:

```
`"Data": {
    "DbContext": {
       "ConnectionString":  "User ID=postgres;Password=password;Server=postgres;Port=5432;Database=db;Integrated Security=true;Pooling=true;"
   
    } `
```

The Npgsql connection in `Program.cs` stay out of the following way:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SubjectDbContext>(options =>
   options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Data:DbContext:ConnectionString")));
```

Nevertheless, the server return me the following error's message:

`fail: Program[0] An error occurred creating the DB. Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 3F000: schema "account" does not exist`

I used the command `docker exec -it postgres` to see the avalaible schemas inside the container and show me this:
`

```
postgres=# \dn+
                                       List of schemas
  Name  |       Owner       |           Access privileges            |      Description       
--------+-------------------+----------------------------------------+------------------------
 public | pg_database_owner | pg_database_owner=UC/pg_database_owner+| standard public schema
        |                   | =U/pg_database_owner                   | 
(1 row)`
```

if anyone could help me to fix this, I'd be really grateful.